# Displaying Mysqli results in a drop down list

Tags: php, mysqli, dropdown

I have a code that when a person logs in it displays certain information automatically related to their account. I'm trying to get this to list information in a drop-down list with each result as a new option. Right now it's posting the results but all in the same line.

[Current Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zzp9.png)

This image shows how the query is currently outputting the results. I'm needing each of those names in a separate line instead of as the same option.

```
<?php
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT u.Name AS Name, u.activation as activation, u.lastlogin AS lastlogin, u.dwForbidTime AS dwForbidTime, u.RegDate AS RegDate, u.email AS email, group_concat(distinct g.szName SEPARATOR '<br />') AS szName, g.byShape as byShape, g.Level as Level
                                    FROM user AS u
                                    LEFT JOIN gamedata AS g on u.name = g.szAccountName
                                    WHERE Name='$user_check'
                                    ORDER BY g.szAccountName DESC
                                    LIMIT 3") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($db));
echo "<select name='character'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['szName'] . '">' . $row['szName'] . '</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

My query outputs fine if I don't try to use a drop-down list but I'm needing to give a select option for a form.

Comment: You have `GROUP_CONCAT()` but no `GROUP BY` in your query. So it's just going to return one row with all the names in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `GROUP_CONCAT()`. That's combining all your results into a single row, with `<br>` between each name. Your `while` loop expects each name to be in a separate row of results.

```
$results = mysqli_query($db, "
    SELECT distinct g.szName
    FROM user AS u
    LEFT JOIN gamedata AS g on u.name = g.szAccountName
    WHERE Name='$user_check'
    ORDER BY g.szAccountName DESC
    LIMIT 3") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($db));
```

You also don't need to select all the other columns if you're only showing `szName` in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score -1):

I used a foreach for testing this and it worked perfectly.

```
$row = array('test', 'test 1', 'test 2');
echo "<select name='character'>";
foreach ($row as $result) {
    echo "<option value='$result'>$result</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: I'm needing it to list a specific column from the database which is szName. It pulls this data from their account name. When I use what you posted it pulls everything from my query into separate results but still keeps the column szName results in the same option instead of separate options.